# I am the fifth of my kind

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Sit down, gather round, listen to my tale
>
> Of a time when humanity would finally fail
>
> To conquer death like it always had,
>
> we've died before, but this time was bad.
>
> In threes they came, spreading like plague
>
> We know many died, but the numbers are vague.
>
> After many a year, the sick called "so long!",
>
> Leaving only the lucky who managed to stay strong
>
> Then I came I came along, and spirits were raised.
>
> A new era was born, you'd be amazed
>
> To live in my kingdom, when life was the best,
>
> When the whole human race put their limits to the test.

Should be pretty easy... So what am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is...**

> **the renaissance?**

Sit down, gather round, listen to my tale
Of a time when humanity would finally fail
To conquer death like it always had,
we've died before, but this time was bad.

> The black death.

In threes they came, spreading like plague

> The black death was a combination of three plagues.

We know many died, but the numbers are vague.

> The amount of people who died are counted in millions, not very precise.

After many a year, the sick called "so long!",
Leaving only the lucky who managed to stay strong

> The survivors. The people afterwards are believed to be better.

Then I came I came along, and spirits were raised.
A new era was born, you'd be amazed
To live in my kingdom, when life was the best,
When the whole human race put their limits to the test.

> The Renaissance. The black death was in the late Medieval era.

**Hint:**

> *Post hoc, ergo propter hoc* could be referencing the fact that people attribute the fact that the humans after the black death were better(X) to the black death(Y).

Comment: Well, you are extremely close. The bubonic plague was never cured with a vaccine though, it was wayyyy before those existed.

Comment: Also, read again, keeping in mind the phrase *Post hoc, ergo propter hoc*

Comment: I think I remember now. The bubonic plague was gotten rid of by getting rid of the rats carrying diseased fleas. Is that right?

Comment: If it weren't for your comment that the plague is extremely close, I'd guess Rot13(Fpvrapr, fvapr vg "pherq" gur cerinyrapr bs eryvtvbhf cerwhqvpr, gb fbzr rkgrag.)

Comment: Mostly it was the cold that killed off the fleas, yeah

Comment: And that second guess is a nice way to think outside the box, but not what I had in mind.

Comment: @Cubemaster didn't the Chinese discover vaccination more than 1000 years ago, later claimed by the Western world?

Comment: I will say, you are not wrong with the Bubonic Plague. However, you are not entirely right either

Comment: @BrendonShaw So close... can you name the age you are talking about?

Comment: and @WeatherVane, I am pretty sure smallpox was the first vaccine, but many societies might have known some of the secrets beforehand.

Comment: @Cubemaster Sorry if my answer looks rushed. It is. I am trying to find the right one before I apply it better.

Comment: @Cubemaster it was termed "variolation" and was practised widely to some effect before Edward Jenner improved the technique, although he might have been the first to notice the connection between cowpox and smallpox.

Comment: Good job. The thing with the threes requires a bit of knowledge about the bubonic plague. If you researched it, you would find that the "black death", as it is called, was actually the combination of 3 plagues. The bubonic, the pneumonic, and the septicemic plagues

Comment: Cool riddle and smart anwer. Kudos to both of you :)

Comment: @Cubemaster Thanks! I will add that to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you the

> Smallpox vaccine? It was indeed cured by vaccination, as far as I know.

Comment: First off, welcome to the Puzzling SE. Secondly, keep in mind *post hoc, ergo propter hoc*. In this riddle, "I" come after this terrible event. It doesn't mean i caused it

Comment: Hmm, is it rot13(Cravpvyyva)? Came later, and we got rid of the problem once and for all.

Comment: Not quite. The answer is more of the product of such a cure, rather than the cause