# Dear ___________, this one's for you

Tags: riddle, rhyme, metapuzzles

> Assemble, fine puzzlers, and hear my tale
>
> I promise, I won't be long
>
> You've seen many puzzles, and tried to prevail
>
> Some were right, and many were wrong.
>
> Today I give you a new type of puzzle,
>
> One that is sure to astound.
>
> You'll have to be flexing every last muscle,
>
> Searching high, low, all around.
>
> For the solution to this vexing verse
>
> Lies not within this page
>
> You'll have to search outside, or worse:
>
> Farther in... how strange?
>
> I've laid the base of helpful clues
>
> Although you never knew it
>
> Just one more clue to light the fuse
>
> So don't you look straight through it!
>
> You know me as the meta-puzzler
>
> At least, some of you do..
>
> Those of you who've known me longer
>
> Have a bit less work to do.
>
> So go on! Start your searching
>
> There's oh so much work to do
>
> I'll continue creeping and lurking,
>
> So do ask if you must have a clue.

HINT #1

> Though your instincts tell you not to, 
>
>  Listen to the words I say. 
>
>  Lingering here will never help you,
>
>  Your instincts lead you astray.

HINT #2

> Seven clues I've given you
>
>  And Seven clues you've solved
>  
>  Though they might seem like nothing new
>
>  They're meant to be involved

Comment: (+1): I love the rhyming! Well done! :D

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Not so much, I can't even fathom how you came up with that. Keep up the effort though!

Comment: @Cubemaster rot13(gur bayl yrggre abg hfrq va gur cbrz vf 'd'. hfrshy be abg?) and are you sure there isnt a wordplay tag? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Unfortunately, nope. Just an arbitrary amount of underscores

Comment: And there is no wordplay tag here! Though I like your style of analyzing it. Gives me some good ideas for the future.

Comment: What was the answer to this?  I think it's been long enough that you should reveal the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Is the answer

> Parseltongue?  That is, the name of the user who submits the answer.

> You've seen many puzzles, and tried to prevail
> Some were right, and many were wrong.

> Presumably, any user who finds the answer has seen many a puzzle, and has submitted many right and wrong answers

> You'll have to be flexing every last muscle,
> Searching high, low, all around.

> I happen to have huge muscles

> For the solution to this vexing verse
> Lies not within this page
> You'll have to search outside, or worse:
> Farther in... how strange?

> The solution lies within.  It's yourself!

> I've laid the base of helpful clues
> Although you never knew it
> Just one more clue to light the fuse
> So don't you look straight through it!
> You know me as the meta-puzzler

> Don't look straight through.  Look at the reflection. You are the  meta-solution.

> At least, some of you do..
> Those of you who've known me longer
> Have a bit less work to do.

> Nobody knows you longer than yourself

Comment: Wow, I wish I had thought of that! Would have made for a great answer, but not what I'm looking for. Think bigger

Comment: "I happen to have huge muscles" The snake flexes ;) +1

Comment: That moment when the OP's answer is wrong and the answerer's is correct ;)

Comment: Witty answer, hahaha. Shame I ran out of upvotes. Will upvote when I can :P

Comment: A mighty fine answer, though not the right one. A bounty for you anyway!

Answer (score 7):

This is only a partial answer.

Taking hint #2, that cubemaster has given seven clues that have been solved, together with the meta-puzzling clue, and that the clues are not on this page took me to cubemasters previous puzzles, among which are titles relating to numbers 1-7.

[We are the first inhabitants](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79004/we-are-the-first-inhabitants)

> Tectonic Plates / Rocks

[As the seconds add up I get further away](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79647/as-the-seconds-add-up-i-get-further-away)

> Yesterday

[I am the last of the three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79073/i-am-the-last-of-the-three)

> Future

[When I'm called forth, times must be tough](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79654/when-im-called-forth-times-must-be-tough) (assuming an intended forth/fourth pun)

> Heartache

[I am the fifth of my kind](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72480/i-am-the-fifth-of-my-kind)

> Renaissance

[Harnessed by the 6th day](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72489/harnessed-by-the-6th-day)

> Fire

[I exist in the middle of the seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78999/i-exist-in-the-middle-of-the-seven)

> Greenhouse

Comment: This is a great spot!

Comment: Hmm quite an interesting theory...

Comment: Adding onto this, there are lines in the puzzle that seem to clue these answers, although I can't match up all of them.

For example:

"So don't you look straight through it!" seems to clue the answer to 7,


"Just one more clue to light the fuse" clues the answer to 6,


"You'll have to be flexing every last muscle" could be cluing 4 (?)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the answer is:

> **Somebody**

How I got there you probably ask,
Well....

> I myself am not sure of this, just read the text backwards (from the end to the beginning) and it made me think that this is the answer,

especially the following lines:

> **Searching high, low, all around**.
>
> For the solution to this vexing verse
>
> Lies not within this page
>
> You'll have to search outside, or worse:
>
> Farther in... how strange?
>
> I've laid the base of helpful clues

means:

> So if it's familiar to someone who knows you it's probably someone who has watched your profile,But actually you said that only **some** of those who know you-
> This is probably alluding to those who have studied your profile well and seen your ranking among all users.
> And just on this page you have to look up and down and find the answer:[image: **enter image description here**]

I hope this is indeed the answer you were looking for, but even if it is not good that there is an opportunity to wish you congratulations on your being in:
**top 8% this year**

Comment: This is an extremely clever answer.  +1

Comment: You guys are making me rethink my own answer! Not quite what I'm looking for, but a quite excellent alternative for sure!

Comment: And thanks for the congrats, btw. Been a great year! Maybe next year I can work on actually learning how to solve puzzles, rather than just make them!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to comment on Fillet's answer so that they take most of the credit, but I don't have enough reputation points. So this is a continuation of that answer. Is the answer:

> Puzzler --- Instead of the word future, Cubemaster mentioned he was looking for tomorrow. Which means there is a 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, & 11 letter count word. We are missing a 7 letter word. Puzzler fits.

Comment: But YESTERDAY and HEARTACHE are both 9 letters long... If 'future' is actually TOMORROW (8) then we are missing a 6 *and* a 7, with two 9s...